# SDL problem in surface to texture transformation

Tags: c++, sdl

I am trying to recreate an easy version of `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` to understand how SDL2 pixel work.

Here is my code to reproduce the function:

```
Uint32 getpixel(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y)
{
    Uint8 *p = (Uint8*)surface->pixels + y * surface->pitch + x * 4;
    return *(Uint32*)p;
}

SDL_Texture *transformSurfaceToTexture(SDL_Renderer *renderer, SDL_Surface *surface, int w, int h)
{
    SDL_Texture *texture = NULL;

    texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, surface->format->format, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC,
                                w, h);
    Uint32 *pixels;
    pixels = (Uint32 *)malloc(sizeof(Uint32) * w * h);

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;

    while (j < h)
    {
        i = 0;
        while (i < w)
        {
            pixels[j * w + i] = getpixel(surface, i, j);
            i++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, pixels, sizeof(Uint32) * w);
    return texture;
}
```

Then I create a main to test if my function worked well:

```
int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SDL_Window      *window;
    SDL_Renderer    *render;

    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("lul", 0, 0, 0, 0, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP | SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);

    render = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_Texture     *texture;
    SDL_Texture     *texture2;

    SDL_Surface     *surface;

    surface = IMG_Load("MC1frame.png");

    int w;
    int h;

    w = surface->w;
    h = surface->h;

    std::cout << w << " - " << h << std::endl;

    texture = transformSurfaceToTexture(render, surface, w, h);
    texture2 = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(render, surface);

    SDL_Rect rect = {500, 500, w * 16, h * 16}; // *16 is because the IMG is very small
    SDL_Rect rect2 = {1000, 500, w * 16, h * 16};

    SDL_Event   event;
    bool        close_requested = false;

    while (!close_requested)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                close_requested = true;
            }
        }
        SDL_RenderCopy(render, texture, NULL, &rect);
        SDL_RenderCopy(render, texture2, NULL, &rect2);
        SDL_RenderPresent(render);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

So I should see in the left of my screen the texture that I have created and at the right the texture created by `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`

And here is the result:

[image]

The good picture is:

[image]

I don't know where I made a mistake!

Comment: What's your original surface `w`, `h`, `pitch` and `format->BytesPerPixel`?

Comment: @keltar the orignial w= 57  h = 32 ,pitch = 228, BytesPerPixel = 4

Comment: Can't reproduce. Can you show your image? Which one do you think is 'correct'? Do you `SDL_RenderClear` on each frame?

Comment: the good one is the right one ! I edit my question to clarify it ! Thanks ! 
And I add SDL_RenderClear() nothing change :/

Comment: Sorry I don't see anything specifically wrong and can't reproduce your problem; it could be tied to original image itself. You don't free memory (can't change image, so not related), don't handle pixel format variations (probably would've produced distorted colours) or wider pitch - all that could matter, but probably not in that case. At worst it could be highdpi issue, but that is unlikely. What's your OS and SDL version? Could you attach exactly the same source image you use in your test? Do you see the same result with `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE`?

Comment: First thank you for your time @keltar !
I don't understand my whole mistake but you are right the bug is due to the image, I use the screen that i post and i don't have any problem.
I look at the source code of SDL to see what are the main difference between our code and I found it, it's due to the blendMode of my texture.
When i add those lines the problem disappear:
`SDL_GetSurfaceBlendMode(surface, &blendMode);
SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texture, blendMode); `